Getting !SSL timeout and TLS connect() error: domain Operation timed out (PJ_ETIMEDOUT)
We are encountering an issue with PJSIP in our Android application. When the app is in a killed state and receives an FCM event related to a call, we initiate the PJSIP library initialization followed by the SIP registration process. However, we are consistently receiving a 503 response most of the time, even though the server is Up and Running with TLS configuration. But its fine with TCP. Here REGISTER request is not reaching the server anymore
Finally we suspecting the issue with TLS connection/handshake.
We are tried with TCP and its working fine in all scenarios.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
